# highcharts col width and border-top

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

Hello I have highcharts diagram and some problem.

1) How can I set the width of my column to the width of the area of the month? (I try change "width" in CSS it's no working)

2)How to remove all borders, but the top border save? (I try change "stroke-width" in CSS it's no working)

Maybe some js config solution have for it?

**I updated post using answers, it's work! Thank all.**

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 54.4, 54.4],
        type: 'column'
    }],
    
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
      pointPadding: 0,
      groupPadding: 0,
      borderWidth: 0
      } 
 }

});
```

```css
#container {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-series rect {
    stroke-dasharray: 45, 1000;
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke: #00ff00;
}

.highcharts-grid path {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean remove all borders?

Comment: remove border-left/right/bottom from columns and save only border-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width can be solved with `pointPadding: 0` and `groupPadding: 0`.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        type: 'column'
    }],
    
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
      pointPadding: 0,
      groupPadding: 0,
      borderWidth: 0
      } 
 }

});
```

```css
#container {
min-width: 300px;
max-width: 800px;
height: 300px;
margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Then you can add:

```
yAxis: [{
   gridLineWidth: 0,
   minorGridLineWidth: 0
}],
```

As [@Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47635782/9019817) did in his answer to remove the borders and lines.

Comment: I tried to combine your answer and the @Alex response (I update my post), but the problem with the white lines between the columns is not solved by these methods. And I still need to add a border-top to each column

Comment: @AlexChirkin I've just updated the JS in my answer to fix the lines between the bars using `borderWidth: 0` in the `plotOptions`. Not sure about the border-top right now though.

Comment: one white lines alive =(

Comment: Sorry, can u help me with it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770182/highcharts-stacked-bar-minpointlength ?

Comment: @AlexChirkin I've just had a look, but I'm really not sure with that question at the moment. Sorry I can't be more help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width with pointWidth:

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointWidth: 40
        }
    },
```

You can remove grid lines with the following:

```
yAxis: [{
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0
}],
```

**Check it out:**

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

   yAxis: [{
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0
}],
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointWidth: 40
    }
},

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        type: 'column'
    }]

});
```

```css
#container {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js">
</script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the width of the chart by adding the `chart: {width: WIDTH},` key value pair to the `options` object as can be seen below.

As for the chart's borders, there is no configuration. You need to add styles to the container div as I did in the snippet below

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        width: 300
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        type: 'column'
    }]

});
```

```css
#container {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="border-top: thin solid black" ></div>
```